# Active record fails on rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby On Rails 6 rc1 and I am having trouble with this active record.

```
class CreateRouteplanners < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :routeplanners,id:true
  t.integer :id
  t.string :destination
  t.decimal :long
  t.decimal :lat
  t.integer :user
  t.boolean :isVisble
  t.boolean :isDeleted
  t.datetime :createdate
  t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

The error i am geting is the following I upgraded from rails 4.2 to 6 and i am not sure what is wrong here.
Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for true:TrueClass
Did you mean?  to_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:id` option is true by default, you either provide `false` (eg. for habtm join tables) or a symbol for a different type (eg. `:string`) for it.  `true` is not a valid value for that option.

Comment: Sorry comming from a c# background always had to declare my ids so in rails u don't is what you are saying but how do u declare what is to be primary key and auto-increment.

Comment: It defaults to an auto-increment int called "id", you can override it, [see the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table) for how :)